# IO Exception processing: 26

Tags: android, android-maps

I used debug.keystore as well as a new keystore but i keep getting the same error. i saw numerous posts about this problem but could'nt find any solution.

this is my map.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical" >


    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:apiKey="07QY1V71kePjxTjGCtnM7cgrccxWizYevUYKFig"
        android:clickable="true" >
    </com.google.android.maps.MapView>

   </RelativeLayout>
```

this is my manifest.xml

```
         <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.bombil.aawaz"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />



<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
<permission
    android:name="com.bombil.aawaz.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.bombil.aawaz.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<!-- Network State Permissions to detect Internet status -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<!-- Permission to vibrate -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>



<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <uses-library android:required="true" 
        android:name="com.google.android.maps"></uses-library>"

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.bombil.aawaz.Registration"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"

    >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name = "com.bombil.aawaz." />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>


        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.bombil.aawaz.TraceLocation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"


    >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name = "com.bombil.aawaz.TraceLocation" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>


        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.bombil.aawaz.HelpMe"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
       android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name = "com.bombil.aawaz.HelpMe" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>


        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.bombil.aawaz.HelpAlert"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name = "com.bombil.aawaz.HelpAlert" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>


        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

     <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
               android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.bombil.aawaz" />  
        </intent-filter>   
    </receiver>


    <service
        android:name=".GCMIntentService">
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name="com.bombil.aawaz.AlertWidget"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

    >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name = "com.bombil.aawaz.AlertWidget" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>


        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

      </application>




   </manifest>
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved , debug key just works during debugging through eclipse , while when u want to use the apk u need to use release key. Also release key does'nt work in debugging mode.